# CGAffineTransformRotate keeps shifting to the left incrementally with every clockwise rotation

Tags: ios, xcode5

This is the code I'm using:

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{

```
                     wheel.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(wheel.transform, 0.57);

                                          }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                 }];
```

The autolayout is turned off so it's not the reason. 
I hope you guys help me figure out the cause of this issue. 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the constraints generated by the IB. If you don't set any it will generate left, top, width and height constraints, and the left/top causes that after rotation the centre of your view is moving in order to keep the top/left corner fix.

[image]
[image]
[image]

You have to set manually centerX, centerY, width and height constraints to keep the center of the view fixed when rotating.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry for my late reply to your answer. I just opened my MB now.     Adding constraints requires enabling autolayout and it really causes a lot of mess in my view. What do you think I should do other than that? By the way thank you for your answer.

Comment: You may try this too:
`[wheel.layer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(wheel.layer.affineTransform, 0.57)];`

Comment: Thank you again for your reply. I tried the code you offered and nothing has changed. The same result as before but now I understand exactly what happens. The wheel doesn't move from its position but the value I specified for the rotation keeps getting reduced every time the wheel rotates clockwise so this is why it seems like it's shifting to the left. Could this be a bug in Xcode 5 or something coz I don't really get what's going on!

Comment: I have just set the constraints you mentioned and that cleared up the mess I used to get whenever I enable Autolayout but that just it nothing new regarding my real issue here!